# Pushing a UITableViewController from a tabBarController embedded view doesn't remove tab bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I have a tab bar controller with 4 tabs and each tab is their own UINavigationController, which is how you're supposed to nest tab bar and navigation controller's together. The initial tab is a TableViewController and works/appears the way that it should. From the tableVC I can push standard view controller's onto the navigation controller with:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
```

and it works properly.

If I attempt to push another TableViewController onto the navigation with the same method it works the same way, but the initial tab bar does not get pushed off screen like it should, it just stays in place.

Why would the tab bar stay on screen even though I am pushing a new VC onto the navigation?

I have tested with multiple instances of different TableVC's and it only happens with a table view controller.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)pushTableVC
{
    TestTableVC *tableVC = [[TestTableVC alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];
}
```

This will push the new table view onto the stack, but the tab bar from the parent VC stays in place and does not get pushed off screen like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the method `setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:` on the view controller you are pushing to correctly hide the tab bar.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

[viewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This worked for me! Do you have any idea why I have to do this for a TableVC and not any other type of VC? I only have this issue where the tab bar is not being pushed on tables. Thanks again!

Comment: That would seem odd. The above should work regardless of the type of view controller you are trying to push onto the navigation stack as a `UITableViewController` inherits from `UIViewController` unless there is something happening under the hood that we are not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `UITabBarController`, the tab bar always stays on screen, even as you push additional view controllers onto an embedded `UINavigationController`. You will see this in any app that has a `UITabBarController` implemented, unless they implement custom behavior to change this.

The `UINavigationController` contains everything above the `UITabBar`, but does not contain the `UITabBar` itself, so it would not be able to push it offscreen.